# Upload image from Library Photos iOS to cakephp

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, cakephp

I'm trying to upload an UIImage that I took from the library photos on iOS to cakephp. The problem I'm really a beginner on cake so I have no idea how it works. I added the plugin:  **cakemanager/cakephp-utils** to cake then added an upload behavior then in my table I initialized my attribute just like this

```
$this->addBehavior('Utils.Uploadable', [
'control_mfront' => [
'fields' => [
  'filePath' => 'control_mfront',
],
'field' => 'id',
'path' => '{ROOT}{DS}{WEBROOT}{DS}img{DS}{model}{DS}{field}{DS}',
'fileName' => 'control_mfront'.date('YmdHis').'.{extension}','removeFileOnUpdate' => false
]
]);
```

and on my Controller on the post I wrote this :

```
   $this->request->data['model_mfront']['name'] = 'model_mfront';
```

until now on the website it works fine but for iOS i didn't understand how should I post the image . is it on NSData format !?
and what next ?!

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your imagedata(NSData) in `base64` string and then send it to server as post request.

Comment: I tried that but once I got it on my php I didn't know what to do

Comment: decode base64 string and create image object and store it somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer 
ok now I succeeded to create an image on php from base64 string but I don't know how to save it to a folder

Comment: That I don't know buddy, how to store it in php as I am working in iOS.

Comment: ok I will try to look for an answer thanks for your help man (y)